# Incomplete lines written into txt file when the file is closed - Android

Tags: android, android-file

The app records the sensor data and write the data into a .txt file into the phone SD card.

During the data collection process, one may press the stop button anytime to stop writing.

The relevant writing part is as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DataCollector {

    File myFile;
    FileOutputStream fOut;
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter;
    BufferedWriter myBufferedWriter;
    PrintWriter myPrintWriter;

    private boolean isStamped;
    private int timeStampNo;

    boolean accelerationWanted;
    boolean rotationRateWanted;
    boolean magneticFieldWanted;

    // constructor
    public DataCollector() {

        isStamped = false;
        timeStampNo = 0;

        accelerationWanted = false;
        rotationRateWanted = false;
        magneticFieldWanted = false;
    }

    public void setStamp() {

        isStamped = true;
        timeStampNo++;
    }

    public void setFilePath(EditText txtName) {

        myFile = new File("/sdcard/ResearchData/" + txtName.getText() + ".txt");

        try {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(myOutWriter);
        myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(myBufferedWriter);

    }

    public void saveData(double[] acceleration, double[] rotationRate, double[] magneticField, long startTime, long currentTime) {

            myPrintWriter.write(currentTime - startTime + " " + acceleration[0] + " " + acceleration[1] + " " + acceleration[2] + " " + rotationRate[0] + " " + rotationRate[1] + " " + rotationRate[2] + " " + magneticField[0] + " " + magneticField[1] + " " + magneticField[2] + "\n");
    }

    public void stopSaving() {

        try {
            myOutWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

No matter in what sequence I call saveData() and stopSaving(), the last line is always incomplete. By right, I do the following in the main activity:

```
dataCollector.saveData();
dataCollector.stopSaving();
```

I save the data FIRST, and THEN stop saving. Why the last line is STILL INCOMPLETE?

Any idea how to solve this? Either make the last line complete or discard it is ok.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using flush before closing:

```
public void stopSaving() {

    try {
        myPrintWriter.flush();
        myPrintWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        myOutWriter.flush();
        myOutWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: The description of the flush function: "Ensures that all pending data is sent out to the target". I thought that would solve it :(

Comment: Where do you close myPrintWriter?

Comment: oooops... I didn't close it at all! But does it really mattter? If so, where should I close it?

Comment: In saveData you are using myPrintWriter to write, so I think you should flush it and close it too. You can do it inside stopSaving (I added it to the code above). Try if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should flush your writer object before you close it..

like below:

```
    myOutWriter.flush();
    myOutWriter.close();
```

and

```
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
```